# How to avoid 404 error with ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rss, asihttprequest

I'm attempting to add Craigslist RSS data to an iOS application I'm creating.

I've followed the instructions in this wonderful tutorial by Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

However, I'm running into a similar problem as the person did in this post:
[NSURLRequest, why does craigslist return a 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843687/nsurlrequest-why-does-craigslist-return-a-404)

I've tried changing the name of my app, that didn't seem to work.  I've thought about creating an entirely new app and porting over the code to see if that makes a difference, but I haven't gone to that extreme yet.

I can't use the suggesstion "To get around the block, use NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest and fake out the User-Agent header" because I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest tool recommended by Ray.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   #define kUserAgentString @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; tr-TR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27"

   [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultUserAgentString:kUserAgentString];
```

Comment: ZhangChn, thanks for the reply.  I've tried that code, I'm still not seeing anything returned.  I'm able to see data returned when I use a Yahoo pipe, but I was hoping to avoid having to use it since it could go away at some point.

Comment: Did you literally take @"New User Agent String Here"? If yes, use @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; tr-TR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27".